# Toggle through divs with z-index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking to toggle the z-index of 3 divs using jquery but I don't know how I would go about doing that. The desired effect I'm looking for is just to click a button that corresponds to the respective div and have the z-index of that div become a larger number in order to show the content in that div. As of now I have each div layered on top of each other.

```css
.toggle-content {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="toggle">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="button" data-content="#1">1</div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="button" data-content="#2">2</div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="button" data-content="#3">3</div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="togglecontent">
    <div id="1" class="toggle-content" style="z-index:9;">1</div>
    <div id="2" class="toggle-content" style="z-index:8;">2</div>
    <div id="3" class="toggle-content" style="z-index:7;">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So then I'm looking for how I can just click a button to have the corresponding div change its z-index to the highest value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look at using jquery's Hide and Show methods instead.  Much easier to execute, and you don't have to worry about the relative z-index of your other elements.

Comment: If you don't want to take @gravityplanx's good advice, look up the [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
$('#toggle').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $( $(this).children().data('content') ).css('zIndex', 5).siblings().css('zIndex', 4);
});
```

```css
.toggle-content {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <div id="toggle">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="button" data-content="#1">1</div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="button" data-content="#2">2</div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="button" data-content="#3">3</div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="togglecontent">
    <div id="1" class="toggle-content" style="z-index:9;">1</div>
    <div id="2" class="toggle-content" style="z-index:8;">2</div>
    <div id="3" class="toggle-content" style="z-index:7;">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```